# How can I stream video from Google Drive by using Windows Media Player?

Tags: google-drive-api

How can I stream video from Google Drive by using Windows Media Player?

As the https://developers.google.com/drive/web/folder describe, I create the public folder *testPublic* and then insert file *123.mp4* to this folder.

I can use the Windows Media Player's OpenURI function to open this URI https://googledrive.com/host/folder-id/123.mp4 and start streaming this video file.

My question is:

1. I found that WMP can't stream the video file which it's locate in the 
   Google Drive's root folder, even if I set the file's attribute `Shared = true`.
2. Is there any file's attribute for third party player(VLC, WMP) do video streaming?
   I have tried the `downloadUrl`, `embedLink`, `webContentLink`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score -1):

You can actually do that using internet download manager. Play the video in your browser and click on the download with IDM box. The popup box you get has a url. Just copy that url and cancel the download. You'd be able to stream the file using this url.